java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected
estoy utizando la librería de Oracle Virtual Assistant 24.02 dentro de mi app hecha con jetpack compose  para tener un chatbot en mi app, sin embargo al momento que le doy cerrar el chatbot me da el siguiente error:
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient'

estoy asumiendo que es un conflicto de librerías, ya probé otras soluciones como añadir una resolutionStrategy  sin embargo esto genera que la app se cierre al abrir.
tengo esta lista de dependencias:
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.0"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'

//compose
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.6"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0"


//di
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

//logger
implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:2.1.21'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36'


//libs
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:$accompanist_version"

//retrofit
//implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit_version"

api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0'

//data store
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

//json path
implementation("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.7.0")

//image loader
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.4.0")

//insets for keyboard
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.30.1"
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets-ui:$accompanist_version"

//charts
implementation 'io.github.bytebeats:compose-charts:0.1.2'
// For Jetpack Compose.
implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:core:1.12.0")
implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:compose:1.12.0")
implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:compose-m2:1.12.0")
implementation("com.patrykandpatrick.vico:compose-m3:1.12.0")

//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'

//implementation "com.heapanalytics.android:heap-android-client:$heapVersion"

//oauth
implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.11.1'

//google maps
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:4.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:3.7.0'

//Scrollbar
implementation 'com.github.nanihadesuka:LazyColumnScrollbar:1.8.0'

//chatbot
// Core dependencies
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1'
implementation 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
//UI dependencies
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
//NO ACTUALIZAR LIBRERIA DEBIDO A QUE CHATBOT NO SOPORTA LAS NUEVAS VERSIONES
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'

//huawei
implementation("com.huawei.hms:hmscoreinstaller:6.6.0.300")
implementation("com.huawei.hms:hwid:5.0.1.301")
implementation("com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.7.2.300")
implementation("com.huawei.hms:maps:5.0.5.301")

//STOMP
implementation 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.6.6'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'

//GLIDE FOR GIF IMAGES
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'

//indigital
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.7.0.300'
implementation 'com.indigitall:android:5.1.+'

Las variables que tengo son:
compose_version = '1.6.0'
        hilt_version = '2.48.1'
        retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
        version_name = '3.0.95'
        accompanist_version = '0.32.0'

Es mi primera publicación, espero puedan ayudarme con este crash, pedí soporte a oracle, y me han mandado sdks nuevos pero no me han podido ayudar con la solución, acudo a ustedes con todas mis esperanzas

Veo que usas la versión 20.0.0 de 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:", se supone que con eso no deberías tener problema, limpia y construye nuevamente tu proyecto.
